# How can I get a log of my time-triggers (of a script) by click It on menù button?

Tags: google-apps-script, triggers, google-sheets

I want to display a log of all the time that my time-triggers fire.
I want to get this by a click on a menu in my spreadsheet.

[--> screen of my triggers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ls8l5.jpg)

Comment: I save them in an ascii text file with a little function called LogEntry() which also adds a timestamp.  When I want to look at them I use drive NotePad or replace all of the line feeds with `<br />` and use HtmlService and showModeLessDialog(ui,title).  It's pretty simple.

Comment: Can you give me a sample code?

Comment: If you give a decent attempt of your own I'll help you to write it.  But you will have to write it.

Comment: Can I use "Logger.log" ?

Comment: You can use anything you want.  It's totally your choice.  It's time to dive into the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll give you a start.  This is my actual logEntry function.

```
function logEntry(entry,file)
{
  var file = (typeof(file) != 'undefined')?file:'eventlog.txt';
  var entry = (typeof(entry) != 'undefined')?entry:'No entry string provided.';
  if(entry)
  {
    var ts = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT-6", "yyyy-MM-dd' 'hh:mm:ss a");
    var s = ts + ' - ' + entry + '\n';
    myUtilities.saveFile(s, file, true);//s is string, file is filename, last parameter is whether to append or not.  This utilize my own utilities library
  }
}
```